# A hash map like container with two-way lookup?

Tags: c++, algorithm, containers

I am looking to store a lot of objects in a hash map type container (fast Google Sparse Hash) as memory efficient as possible. They will be indexed by an `int` - that's their unique encoded "coordinate". A sample of data would look like:

```
map[1] = object1
map[2] = object2
map[3] = object3
etc..
```

The trouble is that sometimes I have an object reference and I need to find it's own coordinate (the indexed `int`). Doing a full scan on entire map and looking for that object is out of the question for performance reasons. Having a separate "reverse" map to index the coordinates based on object is also undesired - because that would literally double the memory usage.

The only sane solution I have found so far is to somehow mark the objects that need access to their own coordinate with an "index" - thus they essentially get a reverse coordinate index. I am not entirely happy with this solution and was wondering maybe I am missing some special container designed just for this? Essentially a two-way indexed container without any extra memory usage?

Comment: [Boost Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: Have you tried [Googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+2-way+map)?

Comment: I am reading on the Boost.Bitmap, but my question is: is it just a glorious wrapper around two std maps or does it actually do something special memory wise?

Comment: "sometimes I have an object reference" Can you use map iterators instead of references to the objects? I think you can get the index value from a map iterator.